# Polymer way of changing css using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, polymer-3.x

I am from **angular**, **react** background getting started with **polymer**.

I have a polymer class lets say **myClass** having this template.

```
<div  id="[[x]]">
```

Here x is property defined in property getter.

```
  static get properties() {
    return {      
      x: {
        type: Number,
        value: 200
      },
}
```

Here if I set value of x dynamically using chrome dev tools console, like `myClass.x = '5'` it works fine and output will be.

```
<div  id="5">
```

same goes true for other **html attributes** like

```
   <div  width="[[x]]">
   <div  height="[[x]]">
```

but now consider a case scenario that I want to give **margin property** dynamically to my `div` in the same way that I am doing with **id, width, height** how can I do it in Polymer?

In **angular** we can do this.

```
<div [style.marginTop.px]="marginTop">
```

Let me know your thought in polmer way od doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, can be achieved by doing something like this.

```
<div style$="margin:{{ x }}px;">
```

Comment: Any insights on how to write if condition inside style$="margin:{{ if ? do this: else this  }}px;" something like this?

Comment: Look into computed properties if you sometimes want the value of `x` to be different.

Comment: @abraham didn't get you what I am asking is like is there any way we can write expression inside style$, in the similar way like we do in angular like this ng-style="{{valueFromJS}} === 'Hello' ? {'color': 'red'} : {'color': ''blue"}"

Comment: The answer is don't do it that way. Use a computed property. Use `<div style$="margin:{{ x }}px;">` but then compute `x` to the result of your logic.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be achieved using CSS variables:

```
:root {
    --custom-margin-top: 20px;
}

div {
    margin-top: var(--custom-margin-top);
}
```

And via JS you can:

```
updateMarginTop(marginTop) {
    this.updateStyles({
        '--custom-margin-top': `{marginTop}px`
    });
}
```